# How to page an array using LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, pagination

If I have an array like this :

```
string[] mobile_numbers = plst.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Mobile))
                                          .Select(r => r.Mobile.ToString())
                                          .ToArray();
```

I want to paging this array and loop according to those pages .

Say the array count is `400` and i wanna to take `the first 20` then `the second 20` and so on until the end of array to process each `20` item .

How to do this with linq ? .

Comment: There's a cool method called Take for that kinda thing

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) methods for paging (but keep in mind that it will iterate collection for each page you are going to take):

```
int pageSize = 20;
int pageNumber = 2;
var result = mobile_numbers.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

If you need just split array on 'pages' then consider to use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) (available from NuGet) Batch method:

```
var pages = mobile_numbers.Batch(pageSize);
```

If you don't want to use whole library, then take a look on [Batch method implementation](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28). Or use this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(
     this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    T[] bucket = null;
    var count = 0;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (bucket == null)            
            bucket = new T[size];


        bucket[count++] = item;

        if (count != size)            
            continue;            

        yield return bucket;

        bucket = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    if (bucket != null && count > 0)
        yield return bucket.Take(count).ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

```
int pageSize = 20;
foreach(var page in mobile_numbers.Batch(pageSize))
{   
    foreach(var item in page)
       // use items
}
```

Comment: How to get the page number ?do i use this method in a loop right ?

Comment: @just_name you should provide page number for page you want. If you need to split you array on buckets, then consider to use MoreLinq Batch method

Comment: how to conclude the page number ,did u divide 400/20 to get the limit of loop ??

Comment: `for(int i =0  i<20;i++)
{
}`

Comment: @just_name with batches you do `foreach(var page in pages)`

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's why I suggested to use batches

Comment: I use visual studio 2008 , i want it simple with a simple loop ,just i want the limit of loop to use

Comment: Added `ToArray()` there: `yield return bucket.Take(count).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

You need a batching operator.

[There is one in MoreLinq that you can use](http://nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.Batch).

You would use it like this (for your example):

```
foreach (var batch in mobile_numbers.Batch(20))
    process(batch);
```

`batch` in the above loop will be an IEnumerable of at most 20 items (the last batch may be smaller than 20; all the others will be 20 in length).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Skip(n).Take(x);` to skip to the current index and take the amount required.

`Take` will only take the number available, i.e. what's left, when the number available is less than requested.